# Highchart legend based on unique series/names

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I can't seem to find anything relevant or useful on this.
My specific use case is that the Series will be an array of objects in the following format:

```
{
   name: 'name_1',
   date: 'date_1',
   data: [[0, y-value]]
}
```

where the x-coordinate corresponds to a category in categories e.g:

```
categories = ['Jan', 'Feb', ...]
```

The problem with this approach is that there will be multiple series based on the number of 'name' of the objects. If there are 5 objects, it will be treated as 5 different series regardless of whether the names are identical or not. This means that in the legend, there will be 5 series as well.

However, in the case where there are identical series/names, I would like the legend to show only unique series/names. This is the jsFiddle that illustrates my pain point - https://jsfiddle.net/qn59dt2m/1/

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Thanks to Sebastian for the solution! While it solved the issue of showing unique series/names, there was work to be done to fix the colors. That is, the colors of the series in the chart are different from those in the legend bar.

As such, what I did was to use ***colorIndex*** to group series by colors.
Here is the jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ypve5qnc/5/

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo

Comment: I found out about linkedTo previously, but doesnt work

Comment: Show the code where you attempted to make it work then, so we can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign each series to the main series (this one which will be shown in the legend) by using the `linkedTo` feature. In your code this line must be removed because disturbs **linkedTo** working:

```
scatter: {
   showInLegend: true,
   ...
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0wjutmbf/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo